# facebook wall search

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I have come across facebook graph api for developers

https://graph.facebook.com/

among others it also offers search service:

```
All public posts: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post
People: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user
Pages: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=platform&type=page
Events: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event
Groups: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=programming&type=group
Places: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,122.427&distance=1000
Checkins: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin
```

however I could not find option which would allow to search the wall of particular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read the wall of particular user, you need to obtain the **read_stream** permission. Refer to the [FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) for more info regarding this permission, and how to use it.